# How can I append to a singular div with same class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem using Jquery appendTo(). I want to clone `vista-empleador` div and append it to the correspondant div and not to all of them. The current state of my code is append it to all the div with class name `lista-empleadores`.

My code:

```
<script>
    function nuevoEmpleador() {
        $(".vista-empleador:first").clone().appendTo(".lista-empleadores");
    }
</script>
```

and HTML

```
<div class="empleadores">

    <div class="lista-empleadores lista-empleadores-1">
        <div class="vista-empleador">

        </div>
    </div>
    <button onclick="nuevoEmpleador()"></button>

    <div class="lista-empleadores lista-empleadores-2">
        <div class="vista-empleador">

        </div>
    </div>
    <button onclick="nuevoEmpleador()"></button>
</div>
```

By the way, I may have more than 2 div with the class name `lista-empleadores` but with consecutive class names also, like `lista-empleadores-3` and so on.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sounds like you are not scoping down the element you give to the `appendTo`.  If you are giving it the `.lista-empleadores` selector, of course it's going to append to all of them.

Comment: What's "the correspondant div"? The parent?

Comment: I assume it's the div before each of the buttons. @isherwood

Comment: I can assume, too. I'd rather not.

Comment: "I want to clone vista-empleador div and append it to the correspondant div **and not to all of them**. The current state of my code **is append it to all the div with class name lista-empleadores**."  It's pretty clear

Comment: Why giving numbers to CSS classes? What do you want to get with them? How -1 is different from -2 or other numbers?

Comment: I forgot my Jquery. There it is.

Comment: @David jquery added

Comment: @Taplar yes, its the div before each of the buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind the click event of the button dynamically, so you have access to the `event.target` or `this` which is the button clicked.  From there you can get the previous div that you want to change, clone the nested element, and append only to that previous div.

```js
$('.clone-lista').on('click', function(e){
  var $listaEmpleadores = $(e.target).prev('.lista-empleadores');
  var $nestedVistaEmpleador = $listaEmpleadores.find('.vista-empleador').eq(0);
  
  $nestedVistaEmpleador.clone().appendTo($listaEmpleadores);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="empleadores">
    <div class="lista-empleadores lista-empleadores-1">
        <div class="vista-empleador">
A
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="clone-lista">Clone</button>

    <div class="lista-empleadores lista-empleadores-2">
        <div class="vista-empleador">
B
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="clone-lista">Clone</button>
</div>
```